# or coundition in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the data where event id is `event_id ='NGO102' or event_id ='NGO103' or event_id ='NGO109' or event_id ='NGO111'`

here is my query

```
select  event_id, orgname,event_date,num_of_event_pa,start_date
FROM event_details a  
INNER JOIN registration b on a.orgname =b.org_name  
where event_date >= '2017-03-31 00:00:00' AND event_date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' or event_id ='NGO102' or event_id ='NGO103' or event_id ='NGO109' or event_id ='NGO111'
 group by a.event_id, a.orgname,a.published_date, b.num_of_event_pa, b.start_date
     order by event_id DESC
```

but its displaying all record i need record which have event_id is 
`event_id ='NGO102' or event_id ='NGO103' or event_id ='NGO109' or event_id ='NGO111'`. where i'm doing mistake please guide me 
thanks

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) 

AND is evaluated first, then OR. You need to use brackets `event_date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' and (event_id = ? OR event_id = ?)`

Comment: in table a having 400 record and table b having 200 record i want to fetch all 400 record either that record  is available  in b table or not so i did 'right join' but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `group by`?  I suspect something may be wrong with your query.

As Kaushik points out, you want `in`.  You should also use meaning table aliases and qualify all the column names:

```
select ed.event_id, ed.orgname, ed.event_date,
       ?.num_of_event_pa, ?.start_date
from event_details ed join  
     registration r
     on ed.orgname = r.org_name  
where ed.event_date >= '2017-03-31' and
      ed.event_date < '2018-04-01'
      ed.event_id in ('NGO102', 'NGO103', 'NGO109', 'NGO111')
order by event_id desc;
```

Note that the time component is not needed on the ate.  The `JOIN` conditions are also suspicious.  I would expect the `JOIN` to be on something like `event_id`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want an `AND` condition on each of those `OR` within a parentheses.

```
..
 AND event_date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND 
(  event_id = 'NGO102' OR event_id = 'NGO103' OR event_id = 'NGO109'
OR event_id = 'NGO111'
)..
```

You can simplify it using `IN`

```
..  AND event_date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' 
    AND event_id IN ( 'NGO102','NGO103','NGO109','NGO111') ..
```

Comment: The `IN` is definitely better, because it can use an index efficiently.